# Three JSON strings in one AJAX request conflicting in Zend

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I have three different request for my ajax:

```
$result = Map_Model_Map_Factory::getCityByRegionAlias($alias);
$resultCountUsers = User_Model_User_Factory::countUserByRegion($alias);
$resultCountPartners = User_Model_User_Factory::countPartnersByRegion($alias);
```

First request works pretty well. But second and third conflicts with each other. If `$this->_helper->json($resultCountUsers);` comes first, then it works:

```
$this->_helper->json($resultCountUsers);
$this->_helper->json($resultCountPartners);
$this->_helper->json($result);
```

I get what I need `countUsers: "1"` but I don't have `countPartners`. And vice versa, if `$this->_helper->json($resultCountPartners);` comes first, then I get `countPartners` without `countUsers`.

Maybe somebody know, what's going on and how I can receive that.

Comment: Have you looked in your browser AJAX viewer, to see what you are receiving?

Comment: yes, when it's upper `$resultCountUsers` i receive `countUsers: "1"` and when it's `$resultCountPartners` upper i receive `countPartners: "1"`.

Comment: (Please don't rollback good edits. Acryonyms are written in upper case, as is the personal pronoun 'I'. In general, explicit requests for help tend to be removed, as a question is an implicit call for help. Thanks `:)`)

Comment: No probs, pleased the solution worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Zend, but there is clearly a problem: you are not providing attribute names for the JavaScript object. I wonder whether you are overwriting each response with the next one.

See what effect this has in your AJAX viewer:

```
$this->_helper->json(
    array(
        'resultCountUsers' => $resultCountUsers,
        'resultCountPartners' => $resultCountPartners,
        'result' => $result,
    )
);
```